# Setup Wordpress over forced ssl connection

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I am in the middle of trying to standardize some Wordpress configs on my network and initial setup requires non-ssl. It seems that css and other scripts won't load over ssl during initial setup.

I am wondering if anyone knows what the "trick" is to setup Wordpress over SSL as the ideal situation is I disable/restrict non-ssl for all future projects

Comment: I want to state the fact this question I made is wrong. The issue is using DigitalOcean load balancers and how they proxy connections. I need to rethink the situation